# VSCode multiple identical workspace-folders with a filter per workspace folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a project with a lot of files (>500) in one folder and something I miss here is that I can easily filter on specific purpose files through the help of the Explorer Filter (CMD+F) but sometimes I need to have a filtered view with an unobstructed view for some global files I sometimes need to access.

So if I have a file list with

```
> a-global.txt
> a-helloworld.txt
> a-byeworld.txt
> b-global.txt
> b-byeworld.txt
> b-helloworld.txt
> c-helloworld.txt
> c-byeworld.txt
```

and I want to work on helloworld I would filter my explorer on helloworld. But sometimes helloworld needs something from the global files, so I would like 2 explorers. One where I will be working in for 95% of the time and for the 5% of the time I need something from global, I could easily look into the second explorer and just select the file I need.

I tried doing it with the Add Folder to workspace but that doesn't allow the same folder twice, when I tried with an upper-level folder which was allowed; Then the filter function still filters everything so this doesn't solve it either.

Anyone has a good idea on how to solve this?